# Incomplete cmd output in java program

Tags: java, cmd, output

In "tree" command I'm getting incomplete output in my program. Could anyone help me to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            String command = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("> ");
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + command);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
            if ("exit".equals(command)) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: expected and actual results?

Comment: is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

The only potentially obvious things I see in your code, is that your command input will take one (and only one command) - and two, you might want to flush like so

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
  System.out.flush(); // <-- To get all your output, before exit?
}
```

Comment: @JavanshirMammadov That's a different question. But you could use a `PrintWriter` wrapped around a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `System.out`.